# Putting a stringstream at the beginning of another

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'm putting information in a `stringstream`, but just at the end of it, just adding stuff. But I need to now put something at the beginning of the one I'm adding stuff to.

Example:

```cpp
std::stringstream stream;
string a = "123";
string b = "456";
ss << a;
ss << b;
cout << ss.str() <<endl;
```

Output:

```
123456
```

The output that I want is:

```
456123
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE: I don't want to create two `stringstreams`, so I can manipulate where I want the things to go.

Comment: streams doesn't work like that. It's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: If you want to change the order of `a` and `b`, you need to change the order of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The stringstream that i have has way too many things to just put it in order, some of those things get calculated after the need to insert those values . This is just an example to be more simple.

Comment: @Ricardoke  - just use `std::list<string>` then and insert at the head of the list. Then when you are done adding items to the list or ready to print, you just traverse the list to build the final string.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by "too many things to just put in order".  Is it really a performance bottle-neck to just create a new stream and append the old stream's contents to it?

Answer (score 2):

Just have a:

`std::list<string> listStream;`

as your stream object

appending to the stream (you can skip the `std::to_string` call if t is already a string)

```
listStream.push_back(std::to_string(t));
```

prepending to the stream:

```
listStream.push_front(std::to_string(t));
```

Converting back to string:

```
std::string s;
for (const auto &tmp : listStream)
{
    s += tmp;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, though it may make more sense to use an `ostringstream` instead of `operator+=` to build up the final `string` to avoid unnecessary memory reallocations. Or, at the least, `reserve()` the final `string` first by summing the sizes of the `string`s in the `list`.